# Kendo Scheduler datasource not Refresh

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I created an mvc application that implements a Kendo Scheduler ...
 The problem: I have a button that makes an ajax call that returns new data to populate the DataSource, but I am not able to populate the dataSource again ...

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Could you please provide code that shows where you have a problem?

Comment: Can you post your answer and accept your own answer, instead of adding (Resolved) in your question? otherwise maybe just delete this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the code I made

```
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")',
                                    type: "POST",
                                    data: { 'checados': checked },
                                    dataType: "jsonp",
                                    cache: false,
                                    success: function (results) {
                                        var result = [];
                                        var event;

                                        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                                            event = results[i];

                                            result.push(new kendo.data.SchedulerEvent({
                                                id: event.ID,
                                                title: event.Title,
                                                description: event.Description,
                                                start: kendo.parseDate(event.Start),
                                                end: kendo.parseDate(event.End),
                                                isAllDay: event.IsAllDay,
                                                recurrenceException: event.RecurrenceException,
                                                recurrenceId: event.RecurrenceId,
                                                recurrenceRule: event.RecurrenceRule,
                                                resource: event.Resource,
                                            }));
                                        }


                                        var resource = sch.resources[0];
                                        resource.dataSource.read();

                                        sch.setDataSource(result);
                                        sch.refresh();



                                    },
                                    error: function () {
                                        alert('Error occured');
                                    }
                                });
```

Comment: Mark this answer as ***accepted*** instead of adding *(Resolved)* in the title.